# The right and better approach for making trigger on MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have 2 tables called `kategori` , `barang`

```
    +---------------------+
    | kategori            |
    +---------------------+
    |                kode |
    |                nama |
    |                no   |                     
    +---------------------+

    +---------------------+
    | barang              |
    +---------------------+
    |                kode |
    |          kategori_id|
    |        kategori_nama|                     
    +---------------------+
```

the relationship between those tables are `kategori.kode = barang.kategori`

so i want to make a trigger `before insert` to update on `barang.kategori_nama` based on `barang.kategori_nama` when i insert new record on `barang` table.

based on that requirements, i make this trigger:

```
BEGIN
SET NEW.kategori_nama = (SELECT DISTINCT from kategori JOIN barang ON 
                         kategori.kode = NEW.kategori);
END
```

this code works if there's same `barang.kategori` exists on the table, so it doesnt work to new record on `barang` table

i make this :

```
BEGIN
    SET NEW.kategori_nama = (SELECT DISTINCT from kategori LEFT JOIN barang ON 
                             kategori.kode = NEW.kategori);
END
```

works on new record on `barang` but it doesnt work if `kategori.kode` have more than one, if the there's more than one `kode` on `kategori` table, then it returns an error

```
error code 1242 subquery returns more than one row
```

so, what's the better approach to solve this?

here's my problem on `barang` table

[image: the problem]

as we can see, if the `barang.kategori` are the first row that be insert, the `barang.kategori_nama` will be return NULL, but when i insert again, `kategori_nama` will be defined

Comment: When you have a `subquery returns more than one row` error, you can either throw a `LIMIT 1` in the subquery with an `ORDER BY` to ensure the record you most likely want is selected, or write the query in such a way that it only ever has one possible value 

Comment: Don't think DISTINCT without specifying which columns should be distinct is likely to be useful..Also if there are many kategori rows with different nama values which satisfy the condition which do you want?

Comment: Also You should not be storing nama in 2 places..

Comment: Seriously your design , process and question make no sense to me , I'm out..

Comment: Sir, when i double check again using your query on the answer section, that's answering all my question, can you pls reanswer again so i can mark your solution as an answer?

Comment: the answer is your explanation on ```SET NEW.kategori_nama =  (SELECT kategori.nama from kategori WHERE  
                         kategori.kode = NEW.kategori);``` so i guess can you pls reanswer again?. the real problem is ```JOIN``` because when i first insert the table, there are no row on ```barang.kategori``` so that's what my ```barang.kategori_nama``` are null on first insert